# How to prove or disprove that $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ have unique factorization theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, field-theory

How to prove or disprove that $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ have unique factorization theorem, where $p$ is a prime number.

My idea is to first show that every polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ can be factored as $a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\dots(x-x_n)$. Showing it is true in degree $0$ (basically UFT in integers), and then prove using induction for higher degree.

However, I seemed failed to show that $(x-x_1)$ is irreducible.

For example $x-4 \equiv 2(3x-2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

Comment: This idea won't work: $x^2+x+1$ can't be decomposed into two linear factors modulo $2$. What do you know in general about UFDs and PIDs? There are several possible approaches. (BTW, $\mathbb Z_p[x]/(x-x_1)\cong\mathbb Z_p$ showing that $(x-x_1)$ is a prime ideal, hence $x-x_1$ is prime and so also irreducible).

Comment: It is not true that every polynomial can be factored in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. Do you know how to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is UFD? You can use a similar approach for $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

Comment: @Kolja I don't know the proof for $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, can you give me some resources for the proof of that?

Comment: @Kolja: I think that the OP means $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as “integers mod $p$”, not the $p$-adic completion.

Comment: Exercise: if $R$ is a UFD, then so is the polynomial ring $R[X]$ (uses [Gauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)).

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks, I thought it was the $p$-adic completion. That makes it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Given any field $k,$ $k[x]$ has UFT. Here is an outline of a proof.

1. Define the gcd of two polynomials.
2. Define division of polynomials.
3. Prove Bezout's lemma (if $\gcd(f, g) = 1,$ then there are polynomials $a, b$ so that $af + bg = 1$).
4. Using Bezout, prove unique factorization into primes.

This is analogous to integer unique factorization.

Comment: This is a full proof sketch, not a hint. A hint may, in my opinion, be something like "Show that Bezout's lemma holds".

Comment: An easier approach is to show that $k[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, hence a principal ideal domain and hence a unique factorisation domain. (In fact, I don't know how to follow your outline without proving these facts along the way.)

Comment: @RobArthan Euclidean --> PID --> UFD is often proven this way; I assumed the author didn't know that theorem.